# ¿Cómo setear correctamente inputs dinamicos?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo unos inputs dinamicos que aparecen en una lista.

```
{
  this.state.resdata.map((item, index) => {
     return(
         <ul key={index + 1}>
           <li>
             <div className="row mx-auto mb-3">
                <label className="my-auto col-sm-5 col-form-label">{item.iddef_reservation + '- '+ item.guestReserva[0].first_name + ' '+ item.guestReserva[0].last_name}</label>
                <input id={"payvalue"+index} onChange={e => this.onChangePayMount(e, index)} type="number" className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-3"  min="1"></input><label className="my-auto col-sm-4 col-form-label">{"Total due  "+item.monto_rate}</label>
             </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
       )
     })
}
```

la siguiente funcion setea el valor que se pone en el input.

```
onChangePayMount(e){

        let cap = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            payMount:cap
        }, () => {
            this.result(cap);
        });        
    }
```

tengo un estado que es un monto total 'this.state.inicialpay'

lo que necesito hacer es que el monto que se valla poniendo en cada input se reste a la cantidad que hay en el monto total, para eso tengo la siguiente funcion.

```
result(descount){
        var total = this.state.inicialpay;
        var rest = total  - descount;
        this.setState({inicialpay:rest}
            , () => {
                console.log("totalrest => ",this.state.inicialpay);
            });

    }
```

mi problema es que al se realiza la resta pero se va restando cada numero que pongo en los input es decir si escribo 12 primero se resta el 1 y despues el 12 y asi sucesivamente.

Espero haberme explicado bien y me puedan ayudar.
Quedo atento a sus comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que te he entendido. Al parecer estás lanzando el método `result(descount)` en el evento `onChange` del input y es por eso que se ejecuta cada vez que el usuario introduce un carácter.

```
onChange={e => this.onChangePayMount(e, index)}>
```

Te recomiendo que para ese calculo esperes a que el usuario haya completado la introducción de datos en el input, por ejemplo a través del evento `onBlur` ó algún botón.